# struts 2 name of field name conflict

Tags: struts2

I have a field in an object

```
public class MyObj {
 private Date qGuardExpireDate;
 ...  
    public void setQGuardExpireDate(Date qGuardExpireDate) {
        this.qGuardExpireDate = qGuardExpireDate;
    }

    public Date getQGuardExpireDate() {
        return qGuardExpireDate;
    }
....
```

I have a getter and setting in the action class (struts 2.3.36) for the myObj definition.

In the jsp I have

```
<s:hidden name="myObj.qGuardEffectDate" />
```

I have other dates in the dataobject that work fine in the same jsp. This one however will not populate the value in the jsp.... 
I was playing around and added this to the dataobject:

```
public Date getGuardExpireDate() {//removed q from name of getter
    return qGuardExpireDate;
}
```

Change the jsp to show the

```
 <s:hidden name="myObj.guardEffectDate" />
```

And that one works fine!!! Returning the same value from the object.  Any ideas why that would be?? It seems to hate that variable name.

Comment: I seem to remember running into something similar years ago and it was how it looked for the get/sets for a property that had only the 1st char lower before the camel case.  Try renaming the property to at least 1 other lower case char at the beginning of the property name. qtestGuardExpireDate for example.

Comment: Also found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4803 .  Based on the comment from Lukasz Lenart getgGuardExpireDate() might work as well